# How to use Broad File System Access to access disk drives in PC?

Tags: uwp

For months I have been searching to access disk drives using recently introduced  **broadFileAccess capability**. But could not find a way. But recently I have come across an app which access all the drives without asking user to select those drives manually using folder picker. How it could be possible? How to access the disk drives using the above api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enumerating drives, you could use **System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives** then pass each **DriveInfo.Name**  to Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync, and recurse for **subfolders**.

**DriveInfo class**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

Example of getting the drives:

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

Please note that you must have the **broadFileAccess** capability enabled for this.

Comment: Thanks for this great info! Since it is not mentioned in the bottom of the documentation page, as it is supported for uwp, I did not look at there.

Comment: However it throws error "System. UnauthorizedAccess Exception: 'Access to the path 'X:\' is denied.'"  when accessing DriveInfo's RootDirectory.GetDirectories() and DriveInfo's AvailableFreeSpace()! Should it be posted as separate question?

Comment: you need broadFileAccess capability enabled to gain access

Comment: and yes it should be posted as a separate question :)